# How to make all pages numbered with the same number in LyX (or LaTeX)?

Tags: page-numbering

Normally, the page numbers would be 1, 2, 3,... However, IEEE Transactions on Magnetics have the same number for all pages instead of putting the numerical page numbers there.  How do I put the same number, e.g. 8101011 on all pages to replace the normal page number?

Comment: \renewcommand{\thepage}{8101011} ?

Comment: Where to put this command? At the very beginning or anywhere?

Comment: Wherever you want it to start.  Before \begin{document} is probably a good idea.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Do you want to add some kind of answer?

Comment: @Johannes_B - That would be difficult without an MWE and a better idea what is going on.